# Publish Q/A statistics over the years: is Stack Overflow quality deteriorating?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, statistics

It would be interesting to see the public statistics of (un) answered questions on Stack Overflow during last 2-3-4 years. How many questions are being answered, per period of time? Which percent of them were answered by topic starter? And so on.

I judge by my own participation. I rarely use Stack Overflow, only if I'm completely stuck with the problem. Back in 2012-2014 most of my questions at least attracted attention and users were really helpful. It encouraged to help other people as well. Nowadays among 20 last questions only one was answered correctly by other user, several questions were answered by myself, the rest just left without attention.

Have I become a more boring person since 2012 so that I can't clearly explain my problem, or has the Stack Overflow community changed?

I know Stack Overflow had Data Mining team, it would be interesting to see some data on public.

Comment: Data up until the last week is available at [data.se]. Otherwise, Stack Overflow publishes its data in a dump available in a number of places. Regarding the downvote; voting on meta doesn't affect reputation, and the existence of [data.se] and the dump has been explained in multiple questions and answers here on meta. One of the reasons for downvoting is "This questions does not show any research effort"...

Comment: I don't care much about reputation. My point is, when I downvote, I always explain my point. Yeah, Data Explorer seems to be what I was looking for

Comment: Explaining votes is not only not expected, is actively discouraged. Neither up nor down-votes require explanation. The signal intended audience is not the poster, but future visitors.

Comment: You can use the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com) or the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com). But you would be able to get more data from the Data Explorer.

Comment: Like any data, in a raw view it does not worth a lot. It's interesting to see something like yearly report with Data Team comments. But in this case I'm really curious so I'll try

Comment: *Is SO quality deteriorating*, yes, if you limit your dataset to new incoming questions.

Comment: I mean, it's a bit expected as well, no? With the way Stack looks a lot for moderation/duplication, I would expect that, as we answer more and more of the "generic" programming answers, our quality (that you seem to only judge by "are questions answered"... which I kinda don't agree with, but whatever) is likely declining. But again, that's how **you** decide to judge SO's quality. For most users, it's different (quality of content > answering every question)

Comment: "Like any data, in a raw view" Well, what sort of view do you want?  You can more or less manipulate any data to skew it the way you want if you have someone else do it for you.  Graphs are a common method of conveying misleading information, even while being totally, "accurate"

Comment: "I rarely use Stack Overflow, only if I'm completely stuck with the problem" That's how you're *supposed* to use the site.  You're not supposed to ask a question about everyday problems you could easily find an answer to with a bit of research.  You should only be asking a new question if the information isn't already readily accessible.  Given how much information is out there on certain topics, that often means it's rather rare for a problem to merit an SO question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at (one way to measure) how posts are received: [what percentage of posts had positive, negative or zero scores](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1017978#graph):

[image]

[For questions only](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1017958#graph) it looks similar, but worse:

[image]

We should also look at [the number of posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1017963#graph), because the number of questions can affect how people vote (very directly in terms of the number of zero-scored posts, but also elsewhere). But considering the fact that the number of posts per year hasn't changed that much since 2013, this isn't all that relevant. Although that might raise the question of *why* it hasn't changed much, which may or may not have something to do with quality.

[image]

The pretty constant decline in upvoted posts and increase in downvoted posts leads me to conclude that either (or both):

- People are more critical
- Quality is on the decline

My own anecdotal evidence is in line with this (that both of the above are true).

Note, however, that this doesn't mean Stack Overflow will go up in flames any time soon - these trends could keep going for many years before things would get particularly bad, or they could very well start naturally evening out at some point, not to mention that Stack Overflow staff could make changes to address this.

---

There are many other factors one can look at. This one seemed to provide a reasonable amount of insight while being quite simple to analyse.

Note that these are just a count of posts, not a sum of scores - the latter would heavily favour older posts, while one might assume the former would not change much over time.

The above are taken from the `PostsWithDeleted` table, so should include deleted posts, although I can't comment on whether or not there might be some posts that are excluded from this.

Comment: Your total is slightly higher as you take all posts, not only Q and A: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1017989 deletedposts is complete, even if there had been redactions or so. Nothing should be excluded from that

Comment: I'd read that differently: If we assume that there is a finite number of programming languages, and there is a finite number of problems in each, there is also a finite number of "new" questions / answers. Nowadays there is probably already a duplicate here on SO. Most of the questions are about applying an existing solution to a certain edgecase, and they won't generate that much votes, as they only help a few people. Votes do not only rank the content, there are bad answers that helped a lot of people and great answers that were only seen by the asker.

Comment: @Yuri narcissistic? Really? You're aware that SO's goal was **always** to be the "existing database of Q/A" for future research, useful for a long time. It was never meant to answer everyone's questions about all programming issues. It's meant as a high quality, low noise-to-signal ratio, repository of knowledge. Some of your phrasing makes it sound like you expect it to be *your* source of help. That's bound to not end greatly, considering the different target of the community :/. That's the cause for the current gripe (new users want answers, old veterans want to keep the site's goal pure)

Comment: @YuriS.Cherkasov "More narcissistic" - if that's what you're reading out of this, then I argue that no data will help you; you're looking for something to back up your confirmation bias, even if that data is shaky.

Comment: Guys, I don't need to prove you anything. The detailed answer and how you react is a perfect confirmation of my assumption

Comment: @Yuri ofc. Is this just not a proof of my last sentence, which is "the goals of new and old users are different"? BTW, I think it's telling that you: a) expected someone to pull that data for you and b)expect the site (at least in the way you post here) to work like your personal help desk. What you see as narcissistic, I see as maintaining the site for what it is. In my eyes though, you are acting narcissistically, since you value your own answers over the goal of the site. It's all in the eye of the beholder, and that is a BIG point of problem between users, unfortunately :/.

Comment: You know, what's really funny? Someone run to downvote my posts, probably to prove this way my point is wrong. Looks like totally mature approach for me, and back us to question of real worth of reputation system on SO

Comment: @Yuri yeah, that's the "meta effect", that some call (to be clear: meta effect is usually the impact of linking your Q on Meta and having more eyes review it. I personally think users who get followed and voted on on the main site also counts, but it's not necessarily the "usual" definition). Personally, I try to never go vote on the main because of meta. The best you can hope is that the downvotes you got amount to a "serial voting" and get automagically reversed by the system :/. If not.... yeah that does suck when it happens

Comment: @Patrice [It was one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707779/yuri-s-cherkasov?tab=reputation).  *One*.

Comment: @fbueckert lesson of the day: go hunt down claims before answering lol. Let's be honest though: it does happen that someone gets a serial downvoter from their meta post. Glad to see this isn't the case. Sad to see that one downvote now = "someone's running to downvote my post". As you said earlier... confirmation bias :/

Comment: @Yuri I also want to say that, as much as you may hate our attitude, we nevwr pushed back on you and always engaged. The first response from us you didn't like, you went 'I don't have to prove anything'. That is incredibly dismissive, and makes reaching a consensus impossible. As fbueckert said.... You were here with a premade conception and weren't looking to talk about it....